# Filtering the @OneToMany collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, crud

I am trying to use the hibernate `@Filter` annotation to filter the returned values of the `@ManyToOne` collection. Because the app uses a "soft delete" (i.e. status change from active to deleted) I would like to filter out the "deleted".

Basic class setup:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "active", defaultCondition = "status = 'A'")
public class Foo {
    private Status status;

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar")
    @Filter(name = "active")
    private List<Foo> fooList;

    // setters and getters
}
```

I use a `CrudRepository` to retrieve the `Bar` objects:

```
public interface BarDao extends CrudRepository<Bar, Long> {
    Bar getById(Long id);
}
```

If I have 1 `Bar` object in the database and 3 associated `Foo` objects. 2 are "active" and 1 is "deleted". However when I run the query on the `CrudRepository` the collection contains all three and the `@Filter` has not been invoked.

Perhaps the use of the hibernate annotation is wrong when using a `CrudRepository` so what would be the solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `ManyToOne` using a List<Foo> instead of just `Foo`?

Comment: Because I wrote the example wrong, I have updated sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`@Filter` will only do the filtering on the same entity only. If yo want to filter the data of join table you have to use `@FilterJoinTable`.

```
Eg: @FilterJoinTable(name="column_name", condition="your_condition")
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work as this is not joined via a join table.